# Compress log file in a shell script

Tags: shell, cron, gzip, jboss7.x

I have an application deployed in JBoss 7.1. I need to compress all rotated files in a gz format. I was thinking of create a shell script in order to do that.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell script sounds good.
Basically, if you want to rotate all files that are older than x do an

```
find -mtime $TIME -exec mv "{}" "$tmp_dir/" {}\;
```

Compress all files in $tmp_dir, remove $tmp_dir, keep the archive. :)

When the rotate script is called next time you can list all created archives sorted by creation data and remove the oldest one if more than N .gz archives exist

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel.  There are probably hundreds (if not thousands) of log compress/rotations scripts in use, so just do a little [google/git-fu](https://www.google.com/search?q=log%20rotation%20cron%20shell%20script) and you will likely find one that you can tune to your needs.

Comment: that's fine but do you know where to set it up?

Comment: Just create a directory where ever you like to hold your maintenance scripts, and just call them from the cron.  There's no specific place to set it up, just do what makes sense in your environment.